# How can I create an object of my clicked elements input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, this

When I click on a color, an object is created.

```js
$(document).off("click", ".color").on("click", ".color", function (event) {
  var result = {};
  $.each($('.color input').serializeArray(), function() {
      result[this.name] = this.value;
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```css
.color{height:100px;width:200px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>

<div class="color" style="background-color:blue">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="laura">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="14">
</div>
```

But I want to achieve that the object of the clicked color is created.

```js
$(document).off("click", ".color").on("click", ".color", function (event) {
  var result = {};
  var this = $(this);
  $.each($(this 'input').serializeArray(), function() {
      result[this.name] = this.value;
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```css
.color{height:100px;width:200px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>

<div class="color" style="background-color:blue">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="laura">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="14">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do like below:-

```
$.each($(this).find('input').serializeArray(), function() {
```

Working snippet:-

```js
$(document).off("click", ".color").on("click", ".color", function (event) {
  var result = {};
  $.each($(this).find('input').serializeArray(), function() {
    result[this.name] = this.value;
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```css
.color{
  height:100px;
  width:200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>

<div class="color" style="background-color:blue">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="laura">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="14">
</div>
```

Note:- I am unable to see the significance of `.off()` method in your code so may be you can just try:-

```
$(document).on("click", ".color", function (event) {
```

Make sure that this change will not affect rest of your other code

Comment: Can you explain what is the importance of `.off(..)` in this line, `$(document).off("click", ".color").on("click", ".color", function (event)` ?

Comment: `.off()` used to remove an event handler from am element:- [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: I know that, but I'm not clear how it affects here? Can you just explain it as a comparison with this, `$(document).on("click", ".color", function (event)`

Comment: @Madhavan.V  actually it have no effect here. But we can't gaurentee, because we don't know about whole code of OP. That's why i din't say anything regarding that

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification. (I need to go through the `.off()` method once).

Comment: Totally agree with Alive to Die--Anant singh

Comment: @Jarla  glad to help you :):). Please check once my note section

Answer (score 2):

You may try this :

```js
$(".color").click(function (event) {
  var result = {};
  $.each($(this).find('input').serializeArray(), function() {
      result[this.name] = this.value;
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```css
.color{height:100px;width:200px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>

<div class="color" style="background-color:blue">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="laura">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="14">
</div>
```